# cannot start Linux Mint Cinnamon anymore - disk full

Tags: linux-mint, disk-usage, startup, cups

hoping for some help as I have searched for ages and tried heaps of things, but getting nowhere...

I shut the lid of my laptop one afternoon (putting it to sleep) and then next day went to use it (battery had run out I think) and it would not start up normally - just a black screen with a flashing dash for ages...  eventually it came up in terminal asking me for username and then password. While trying some things there is often the sudoers is world writable message and I have discovered the `/dev/sda2` is 100% full after using `df -h`
I cannot figure out what is using up all the space or how to do any kind of reset/restore back to the last state that worked...

the output of `sudo du -x /dev/sda2 | sort -n | tail -30` which is `0`.
Or is it `sudo du -x / | sort -n | tail -30`? which gives sort: `write failed: /tmp/sort5DgezA: No space left on device`

I managed to get Mint to start again after using a liveUSB and happening upon a large file somewhere and deleting it. Then I installed ncdu.

A few more times, the disk has just filled up to the point of not starting up anymore. It seems to be the error_log file in var/log/cups that gets over 100Gb... anyone know how to fix this bug?? thanks

Still having issues - error log grows quickly every time i restart - what could be causing this?
[image]

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for how to merge your accounts and be able to edit your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster refuses to listen to the advice given by members of this stack

Answer (score 0):

If you have any unnecessary data (downloaded photo, meme etc.), you can remove it and gain few MBs. It'll make searching a bit easier. Also it should let you install ncdu (if you haven't it). It's lightweight and really easy-use tool which should help you a lot.

`sudo ncdu -x /`

Notice that `-x` is going to limit searching just to filesystem mounted to root `/`.

Let me guess – the problem lays in Trash. One of the
`~/.local/share/Trash/files`
directories (indeed, root has it's own Trash and it loves to hold huge amount of data).